# Revit FacingOrientation gives wrong orientation for Skylight

Tags: revit-api, revit

I get wrong orientation for skylight(a Window family instance) by FacingOrientation property.

FacingOrientation is normally same as the GeometryInstance.Transform.BasisY but in the case of

rooflight it seems that the correct orientation comes from BasisZ.

Any explanation?

Comment: Hey @ali, typically the facing orientation is a combination of the item's orientation as well as the view's. Have you checked both?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen with other content when the content wasn't created correctly/consistently.

If you compare the family definition with another family, I suspect you'll find that the orientation of the planes used is backwards.

Comment: the symbol definition(not the instance) faces correct orientation when opened in it's editor. How could I check the plane orientation is wrong or not?